# I will invite my friends

Tags: meaning, possessives

a) If we go on a picnic, I will invite my friends and you invite yours.

b) I used to hang out with my friends in that gym.

Does 'my friends' in these sentences mean 'all of my friends' or could it mean 'some of them'?

I think technically it means all of them, but in practice it could mean either!

Comment: Why would it technically mean "all of them"? It might in some contexts, but generally it just says you're referring to a group of people that are all your friends. If I tell you I'm *wearing my socks* would you take it to mean I put all of them on?

Answer (score 3):

Pragmatically we understand "my friends" to mean "some of my friends" in both cases.  This can't be analysed from the grammar or structure, but from the understood context of what "inviting to a picnic" entails.

Comment: "some *of* my friends" sounds better, too small to suggest as edit. Otherwise good answer

Comment: @Imus: It's a pretty "serious" error (as in *No native speaker would ever make that mistake in speech, even if they might **feasibly** fail to **write** it correctly through careless inattention*). So I've fixed it, to avoid the implication of your "sounds better" (this isn't a matter of "better" or "worse" - it's "acceptable" or "unacceptable").

Comment: Guess my wording was too careful (?) since I'm not that familiar with this stack. I should have known that correct spelling is relatively more important here since it is meant specifically for people who want to learn to write english correctly. I fully agree with your correction.

Comment: Thanks ff.  Yes, that was a failure to produce correct English, through inattention.